# How to implement SCIM filter without multiple 'or' operator?

Tags: java, rest, scim

In a POST /.search operation, I want to implement a filter on the users by sending the usernames in the payload.
The filter defined as `"filter": "userName eq "abc" or userName eq "def" or userName eq "xyz""` works fine. Since SCIM doesn't support the 'in' operator, I cannot make this query concise any further.
Is there a way to achieve something like `"filter": "userName in ("abc","def","xyz")"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible - RFC 7644 Section 3.4.2.2 outlines the operators, and what you're looking for is not part of the standard.